# use an HTML button to invert a bool function?

Tags: javascript, html, boolean

Beginner here, go easy on me, I have a simple problem, but I keep getting errors. 
My code is very simple, all I want is for this button to invert my bool so that different content can pull from that bools state to change certain content on the fly. However, when the button is actually clicked I get this error in the console:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Br1c1 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (File.html:32)"
```

line 32 is the line where my button is defined.

All I want is the button to invert my bool function.

```
<script>
   boolean Br1c1 = "true";
</script>

<button class="button" id="r1c1" onclick="return Br1c1 = !Br1c1;"></button>
```

Comment: There's no data types in javascript. Instead of `boolean` use `var Br1c1 = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var Br1c1 = "true";
<button class="button" id="r1c1" onclick="Br1c1 = !Br1c1; return true;"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change boolean by var like that:

```
var Br1c1 = "true";
```